# How to write a Windows Java program using and ODBC database driver?

Tags: java, windows, jdbc, odbc

It's well known to me that since Java 7 there is no more jdbc:odbc bridge to use in order to write a Java programa in a Windows platform, as it was removed at least in Netbeans.  That's what now I have found out while investigating the issue.

But then, does this mean that I can't write a Windows Java program and use an ODBC database driver?  All what I have seen is samples exposed before this happened using the former Sun's original way of using its bridge, but today that is not possible anymore.

So, is really there a simple way to write in Java for ODBC capable databases?  All what I have seen as possible is using DataSource objects, but in no case have I had any success, because it is not so clear on the use of the context object and the DataSource object.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not use JDBC directly?  AFAIK all the major DB servers have JDBC support these days.

Comment: Since your environment is Windows and your database needs ODBC have you considered writing your app in C# instead of Java?

Comment: Yes I have.  The problem is that by now this satellite application is already written in Java and this small database engine is needed to write an interface with which some informations has to flow in both directions with the other original database which already has a true JDBC driver.  But I still consider a bit discriminating not being able to get plugged-in from a Java program to an ODBC driver these days.  Of course, I will have to get a solution like writing code in C#, as the vendor doesn't offer a JDBC driver for their small engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use an ODBC bridge driver, just not the one provided for free from Sun and bundled into the JDK.  It was part of the JDK since 1.0, but they removed it from JDK 8.

You will have to purchase one or write your own.

I would advise against relying on this class.

You should prefer 100% Java type IV JDBC drivers.  There's no good reason for sticking to ODBC for Java.

Comment: Well, it happens that until now the ODBC driver provider for the database for which I need to write a satellite applications doesn't yet provide a JDBC driver.  Unbelievable as it seems, it's the true.  I think they support more a Windows programming base.  And I still need to know how to solve using a Windows-based datasource with this ODBC driver within Netbeans but I've been unable to find how to that.  All what I have tried gets me a "non-suitable driver has been found..." or so.

Comment: Better buy one from them.  Or get another database.  That's rubbish.

Comment: "No suitable driver" means that a driver class was loaded, but the URL you gave was incorrect.  Which driver class did you provide?

Comment: I was trying to use the (by then) popular Class.forName(sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver), but when I run the program in Netbeans 8 it says it doen't have that class. So I searched and found out that in this version that class has been removed.  I think it could probably work importing the jar where it did exist, it should work.

Comment: Yes, they took it out of the JDK.  Has nothing to do with NetBeans.  It was never in a JAR - it was part of the JDK since 1.0, but was removed from JDK 8.  You'll have to find something else.  I would not advise proceeding with this class.

Comment: If you are still considering going down the odbc bridge route, we offer an enterprise grade jdbc-odbc bridge: https://www.progress.com/jdbc/sequelink as an alternative to oracle's bridge. Please note that I work for them.